# Submit image border in Safari and Chrome?

Tags: html, css, button, input

I have a submit image button:

```
 <input id="sbutton" type="image" value="&nbsp;" />
```

Styled like that:

```
#sbutton {
    text-indent: -99999px;
    border: 0;
    background-image: url('submit.png'); 
    width: 201px;
    height: 37px;
}
```

It works perfect in Opera in Firefox the button size is about `10x10px` and in Safari and Chrome it has some kind of strange border (like `iframes` have), and I have no idea how to get rid of that?

Thanks :)

Comment: for the size problem, try adding `display: block`. I'm pretty sure a button is an inline element.

Comment: Here you go: tinyurl.com/2ugzj6j It works ok in Opera, has border in Safari/Chrome O.o Firefox selects it when clicked. I guess input image isn't too well supported (?).

Answer (score 1):

Could it be an outline? Set:

```
 #sbutton:active,
 #sbutton:focus
 {
  outline: none;
 }
```

Try that out.

Comment: It's not a outline, I guess it's the default border for all inputs, border: none and outline: none doesn't change a thing O.o

Comment: Do you have a live example? It might be inheriting some values from higher up the cascade. A screenshot would help too.

Comment: I'll upload it in a few minutes.

Comment: Here you go: http://tinyurl.com/2ugzj6j It works ok in Opera, has border in Safari/Chrome O.o Firefox selects it when clicked. I guess input image isn't too well supported (?).

Comment: Got a Polish 404: 404] File Not Found : Plik nie istnieje.

Comment: rofl, you have edited your solution after my answer and just copied it.

Answer (score 1):

Changed type from image to submit as I was using a background image in CSS and this fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
border:none;
```

rather than:

```
border:0;
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is a right solution for this question:**

```
:active, :focus { outline: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this happens for image inputs with no src attribute.  You can give it an src, as in this post:

[input type="image" shows unwanted border in Chrome and broken link in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108983/input-type-image-shows-unwanted-border-in-chrome-and-broken-link-in-ie7)

OR, you could just use a type="submit" input instead of type="image", if you're setting the background image anyway.