# input type="image" shows unwanted border in Chrome and broken link in IE7

Tags: css, image, input, border

I have not found a solution yet...

I tried everything

```
border:0;
border:none;
outline:none;
```

without any luck...and the funny thing is the broken link icon in IE7 which overlaps my image.

Any suggestion?
[link here](http://eezzyweb.com/)

HTML (generated by WordPress)

```
<form id="searchform" method="get" action="http://eezzyweb.com/">
   <div>
  <input id="s" name="s" type="text" value="" size="32" tabindex="1"/>
  <input id="searchsubmit" name="searchsubmit" type="image" value="" tabindex="2"/>
   </div>
</form>
```

CSS

```
input#s{
position:relative;
width:245px;
height:28px;
border:0;
vertical-align:bottom;
background:url(images/input-search-bkg.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

#searchsubmit {
display:inline-block;
background:url(images/submit-bkg.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
width:30px;
height:30px;
border:0;
vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

Firefox and Opera render the image button ok, but in Chrome and Safari I get that grey border around it. 
IE 7 and 8 add a symbol (broken icon?) over my image... I am baffled.

Comment: And a link or screenshot of what you see.

Comment: Why don't you use the <img../> tag instead?

Comment: can you change the `border:0;` to `border:none;` for me?  I'm inspecting it with chrome.

Comment: @Stephen I solved it using the solution below, even though I used only CSS in another website and I did not have any problem (and the page validates). If you use Chrome and you have FireBug Lite installed you can edit the CSS on the fly like you probably do in Firefox. Thank you very much anyway

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are using the image as a background. Why not set it as the src property of the button ?

```
<input src="images/submit-bkg.png" id="searchsubmit" name="searchsubmit" type="image" value="" tabindex="2"/>
```

When you set the `type` as `image` the input expects an `src` attribute as well..

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-src and http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.1

Comment: This is a Chrome/Safari bug. When you give it a src attribute no image is displayed, instead only the grey box around the image is rendered. The only way to get the image is with background-image - which always gives you an unwanted grey box.

Answer (score 10):

For reference, if you want to stick to using CSS to give the button an image, for reasons such as providing a :hover or an :active rule, you can keep your code as is and add the button an invisible image, i went with:

`<input type='image' src='invisible.png'/>`

Which means its a completly transparent image, size doesnt seem to matter, but i went with 1 px by 1px.

Comment: it should probably be an invisible gif, for ie6 compatibility reasons.

Comment: This is a little old. But here goes, you don't have to use a gif. You can also just use a 8bit PNG, this is supported by IE.

Comment: This is also useful when using css sprites as the background image via class.  The transparent gif reference gets rid of the border in Chrome.  BTW, I prefer .gif because it's less than half the size of a png (likely due to the container headers) at this size.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
input[type="image"]:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Chrome, IE, and Safari parse the code foolishly.

```
<input type="image" src="bleh.png">
<input type="image" src="bleh.gif">
```

is not parsed the same by these browsers as

```
<input type="image" src="bleh.png"><input type="image" src="bleh.gif">
```

Put all of your image inputs on the same physical line in the coded document.  I just about punched a whole through my monitor with the same problem until I realized this.

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly but it works...

```
<input id="saveForm" style="border:0px;" type="image" name="submit" value="Submit" BORDER="0" src="./images/button_submit.png" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
a:active {
 outline: none;
}
a:focus {
 -moz-outline-style: none;
}
a, input {
 outline-color: invert;
 outline-style: none;
 outline-width: medium;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything useful either