# chrome border issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, border

I only have this problem in chrome. How remove the border around the image? please see the fiddle in chrome.

```
<form>
    <input type="image" class="searchbox_submit search_btn" value="">
</form>
```

```css
form input[type=text]:focus, form input[type=password]:focus, textarea:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.search_btn {
    background: url("http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yu/r/yo348KDuskF.png") no-repeat scroll 0px -200px transparent;
    height: 25px;
    width: 30px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    outline-width: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
}​
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/TXYg6/

Comment: Side note: your image is offcenter, it should be width: 30px, height: 30px, `url("http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yu/r/yo348KDuskF.png") no-repeat scroll 0px -192px `

Comment: change type from image to submit

Comment: possible duplicate of [input type="image" shows unwanted border in Chrome and broken link in IE7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108983/input-type-image-shows-unwanted-border-in-chrome-and-broken-link-in-ie7)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using `<input type="image" />`, so [a `src` attribute is expected](http://developers.whatwg.org/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#image-button-state-%28type=image%29). You haven't specified one, so Chrome shows a grey border, in the same way [it does for an `img`](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/fNbF6/) with no `src` attribute.

If you want to stick to using `<input type="image" />` and using a CSS sprite, you're going to have to specify *something* as the `src`, such as a 1x1 transparent "blank.gif".

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/TXYg6/14/

However, that just seems horrible. Instead, I recommend switching to `<input type="submit" />`, which [solves the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/TXYg6/25/).

Comment: Or an alternative is to just use `type="submit"` since by default a `type="image"` will submit the form as well.

Comment: @animuson - I think `<button type="submit" />` is better still, since you don't actually have an input associated with the button.

Comment: @Madbreaks: I don't think there's such thing as a `type` attribute on a `<button>`, nor is a button a self-closing tag... besides, `<input type="submit" />` is not actually an input unless you give it a `name`.

Comment: @minitech: There is, and the missing value default is `submit`.

Comment: @animuson: Huh. I need to get out more.

Comment: @minitech You are wrong: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.5 -- and correct it's not a self-closing tag (see my answer) that was just for terseness in a comment.  As for `<input />` not being an input?  I'm a fan of the *semantic web*.  Use the right tool for the job - just because an `<input />` works doesn't it mean it's the *right* element to use.

Comment: @minitech I agree.  But you also told me there was no such thing as a `type` attribute on the button element. I at least *had* to call you out there.  :)

Comment: @Madbreaks: Yeah, Googling beforehand helps :(

Answer (score 2):

replace it like that with submit type

```
<input type="submit" class="searchbox_submit search_btn" value="">
```

correct your css height and width

Answer (score 1):

Give it a blank image as a `src` using a `data:` URI. Since you're only concerned with Chrome, there's no problem:

```
<input type="image" class="searchbox_submit search_btn" value="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAadEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAFBhaW50Lk5FVCB2My41LjEwMPRyoQAAAA1JREFUGFdj+P//PwMACPwC/ohfBuAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TXYg6/23/

Answer (score 1):

Chrome gives a border/outline thingo to any image without a src, you could set the input type to 'submit' and this will go away.

Alternatively, use an  with a src and trigger the submit from this, but you may as well just use a type="submit"

[unwanted chrome borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108983/input-type-image-shows-unwanted-border-in-chrome-and-broken-link-in-ie7)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need that att type="image"? Because that's the thing causing the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Semantically I'd say use a `button` since you don't actually have an associated input value, and as such it's *not* an input:

```
<button type="submit" class="searchbox_submit search_btn"></button>
```

From [the docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.5):

> Buttons created with the BUTTON element function just like buttons
>   created with the INPUT element, but they offer richer rendering
>   possibilities: the BUTTON element may have content. For example, a
>   BUTTON element that contains an image functions like and may resemble
>   an INPUT element whose type is set to "image", but the BUTTON element
>   type allows content.

Cheers