# input type=“image” shows unwanted border in Chrome

Tags: html, css

html:

```
<input type="image" />
```

css:

```
input[type="image"]
  {  border:0;
     border-color:transparent;
     background:transparent;
     width:150px;
     outline:none;
  }
```

i don't want to use src="img url", i want to use background:(url) 
i have added border:0 but still border is coming in chrome

JSFiddle > http://jsfiddle.net/akash4pj/PYKfr/1/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108983/input-type-image-shows-unwanted-border-in-chrome-and-broken-link-in-ie7

Comment: Could you show us in a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: mr. gil border:none is not working

Comment: I looked it up a little and it appears that the border is an indicator for an empty placeholder. It disappears when the input has an image. I might be wrong, but so far this is how I see it.

Comment: imtheman jsfiddle added

Comment: @user3171894 When I added an image to it, the border disappeared. http://jsfiddle.net/imtheman/PYKfr/2/

Comment: You can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10542868/1420186

Answer (score 2):

Add an 1x1 GIF to the `src` attribute will solve the problem:

```
<input type="image" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" />
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qyhF8/)

You can find the answer from a similiar question here: [chrome border issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10542868/1420186)

Comment: this is working for me in Chrome 36. Problem for me was I was using an image input but setting the background image using css, so Chrome automatically put some square around the input... border and all that doesn't fix anything

Answer (score 0):

Use rather the following CSS property :

```
border:0px;
```

or

```
border:none;
```

If it doesn't work, check your parent tag, maybe your div or span container have a border set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
input[type="image"]
{
    border:0;
    border-color:transparent;
    background:transparent;
    width:150px;
    outline:none;
    border-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the border: none property should fix it:

```
input[type="image"]
{  
    border:none;
    border-color:transparent;
    background:transparent;
    width:150px;
    outline:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in you code `{` you are using 2 times. also you have to call image as CSS `background` property.

you can use like this.

```
input[type="image"]{
  border:0 none !important;
  outline:0 none !important;
  -webkit-border:0 none !important; 
  border-color:transparent;
  background:transparent;
  width:100px;
  height:25px;
  display: block;
  background: url("http://lorempixel.com/100/25")
}
```

here is the Working Demo. http://jsbin.com/kiherove/1/

Comment: still border is coming but ur img hide it

Comment: Add these lines please; it will force to keep the border 0 `border:0 none !important;` `outline:0 !important;`

Comment: what if you add `Browser prefixes` like make any impact? 
 `-webkit-border:0 none !important; `

Comment: by adding vendor prefixes for safari and chrome is it works? check my above comment..

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in Chrome when you adjust the Zoom to greater or less than 100%, borders will appear on images. You may not have noticed that the Zoom got adjusted. Its a bit of a long shot, but if your CSS is correct, that may be what it is.