# when we have a double border in a table , how do we fill in the gap beetween the two borders

Tags: html, css

When we use CSS to format a table and we have a double border that is border around both table and td.
How to fill in the space between the two borders

Comment: Hello & welcome to SO. Please let us know what you have already tried and take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for some tips on how to format questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `border-collapse: collapse` on the table, see if that produces the effect you want.

Answer (score 1):

use in your css  `table{border-collapse: collapse;}`

Comment: Five minutes after posting my answer, you post the exact same thing?

Comment: this is not the same thing bro , in my answer there is css code

Comment: And in mine there is not?

Comment: no , cuz some ppl don't now how to write css code i give him a code for copy and paste in css file only .i know u explain will

Comment: So basically you're implying that OP is clueless? ;)

Comment: let it be ,  i need ur help on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344374/input-type-image-shows-unwanted-border-in-chrome