# Trying to remove border around PayPal input in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, paypal

I'm trying to remove this border around my PayPal input as well as center align the text.

It works fine in Firefox but bugs in Chrome.

Here's a link to what I'm working on.

http://jsfiddle.net/R28f7/1/

I've tried this focus fix, but no luck.

```
textarea:focus, input:focus{
outline: 0;}
```

I have been trying to fix this for a while now and any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542868/chrome-border-issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to change the HTML markup of the input type to **button** ?  Doesn't seem like you are using it as an image anyways.

```
<button type="submit" class="button_fix">Order Now</button>
```

Since you are trying to align your text to the center, remove the padding from the right and left and apply `text-align:center;` Here is an updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/DL6QU/7/

Comment: I can change the input to button, but it doesn't link to the right PayPal page. Is there a way I can get the button to still link properly?

Comment: Updated answer with new fiddle, use the button element with type="submit"

Comment: Also added a CSS rule at the bottom to allow the mouse to become a hand when hovering over the button.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/R28f7/3/)**

**HTML:**

```
<input type="submit" class="button_fix" name="submit" value="Order Now">
```

**CSS:**

```
.button_fix {    
    display:block;
    background-color:#c0392b;
    text-align:center;
    width:200px;
    padding:10px 35px;
    color:#fff;
    /* Safari 3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android 1.6- */
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px; 
    /* Firefox 1-3.6 */
    -moz-border-radius: 8px; 
    /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Safari 5, Chrome, Firefox 4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
    border-radius: 8px; 
    font-size:2em;
    font-weight:200;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin:10px auto 0px auto;
    outline:none;
    border:0;
}
```

Hope this helps